# How to make HTML input get automatic with and ignore default size attribute value of 20

Tags: html, css, styles

Is it possible to make an input ignore the default size attribute value of 20 when size is not present. I want it to scale with it's container just as a select-box does (see example).

Look at this example, when I set size to 1 it works but without size minimum size is 20...

HTML

---

```
<div class="form-item-group">
  <div class="form-item">
    <label>Label 1</label>
    <input placeholder="Value" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-item">
    <label>Label 2</label>
    <input size='1' placeholder="Value" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-item">
    <label>Hello world</label>
    <select>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

---

```
.form-item-group {
  .form-item {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }

  label {
    display: block;
  }
  input {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }

  select {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L6Lytsfj/3/

Comment: That's not CSS. What is that sass or less?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like that with `jQuery`

```
 $('input').filter(function(){
         return !$(this).attr('size');
    }).attr('size','1');
```

This will set the size attribute to *1* if size attribute is not specified.